# convert a jpeg into url for css

Tags: css, url, jpeg

I am new to web design and I think I need to convert a jpeg into a url. I have an image saved locally on my computer. An example website that I am using as a reference has a one page for their html/source code and a different page for their css. All of the images are listed under the css page, however, they are typed in as a url. For example url(..green sea.jpeg) When I try to replace their css code with my image, it can't be found. I know I'm new, so I figure I must be making a simple simple mistake, but everytime I try and look it up online, I find directions on how to convert a jpeg into a url and it looks like you need another kind of software to do this, but I'm not exactly sure. Any help/direction would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a localhost webserver or are you just playing with HTML files on your computer and opening them in a browser?

Comment: Are you using inline CSS or an external stylesheet?

Comment: someone down voted you. I up-voted you because new people need answers too.

Comment: Conner- I am doing the latter. Just opening a new html file in dreamweaver and then saving and testing any changes in my browser.

Comment: Wex, thanks for the help, but I am new to this and don't know whatthe difference between inline CSS and an external stylesheet is. I think I am using an external stylesheet because the css code is on a different tab than the source code, which I all just html, I believe. (I am working in Dreamweaver)

Answer (score 1):

When you replace your image name for the one you see in the CSS:

```
url(..green sea.jpeg)
```

...make sure that the image you are wanting to use is in the same location (folder / place) as the green sea image.

So if I want to replace it:

```
url(..myNewimage.jpeg)
```

I would make sure it was in the same place as the image I'm replacing it with.

ALSO, I just noticed that your path is wrong. You have ".." when it should probably be "../".

So try this:

```
url(../green sea.jpeg)
```

Answer (score 0):

The url you need for your code is just wherever you have posted the image on your server in relationship to the css file. For example, if your directory is structured like this:

```
/CSS
  -style.css
/JS
/images
  -green-sea.jpg
index.html
```

Then your url would be (../images/green-sea.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried that but it still didn't work... So two questions. First what does the .. before the rest of the directory structure mean? Second, does it matter if my image files are located in a different folder from the demo website. I made a new local folder to hold all of my website files and images. When I referenced the css and javascript files in my source code, I used the location of the new local folder I created.  Basically what I've been doing is taking the bits of code from this demo website I downloaded and changing it to be my own words and images.

Comment: 1. the `..` means "go up one level OUTSIDE of this directory and into the following directory". If your images folder was INSIDE your css folder, then you would leave out the `..`.

Comment: Your local site's directory structure should look exactly the same as your hosted site. This will save you a lot of headache. Since you are using a relative url (meaning you don't have the full `http//` path), you will have to have the images in the same exact path structure as it is locally in order for it to work.

Comment: If you downloaded a demo site and you are trying to update it, you should make a copy of it and then use the same structure they already have set up. Put your images in the same images folder they are already using.